# How can you use PHP GD imagecrop on a PNG whilst maintaining transparency?

Tags: php, image, png, transparency, crop

Whenever I call PHP GD's imagecrop() on a PNG with transparency it is turning the transparent part black instead of maintaining it.

I have recently written a function to scale transparent PNGs whilst maintaining the transparency (see below), so I understand about using imagecopyresampled etc.

```
function scale_png($image, $resize_w = FALSE, $resize_h = FALSE, $alpha = 127)
{
    $src_w = imagesx($image);
    $src_h = imagesy($image);
    if (! $resize_w) {$resize_w = $src_w;}
    if (! $resize_h) {$resize_h = $src_h;}
    $output = imagecreatetruecolor($resize_w, $resize_h);
    imagealphablending($output, FALSE);
    imagesavealpha($output, TRUE);
    $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($output, 255, 255, 255, $alpha);
    imagefilledrectangle($output, 0, 0, $resize_w, $resize_h, $transparent);
    imagecopyresampled($output, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $resize_w, $resize_h, $src_w, $src_h);

    return $output;
}
```

This function above is working fine, but when I also try to do imagecrop() on the same PNG this is when I get the black background.

Is there any easy way of performing this crop successfully? I can't seem to find any good examples.

I would rather not have to write another complex function like the one above in order to crop the image out using x, y, w, h and imagecopyresampled() if possible, as it's a major ball ache.

Any GD boffins out there care to impart their valued knowledge on me?

Comment: @cmorrissey My question was whether there is a way to do this without writing a function, and if not then what that function may look like. But thank you for the completely useless comment and downvote when it's actually a legitimate question.

Comment: We aren't hear to write the code for you, if there is an error with your code we can help.  You have an example of a resize function it is trivial to modify this to crop an image, you can also Google this and you will get 100 different resources.

Comment: @cmorrissey Clearly it's not trivial for me, or I would have done it already...probably in less time than it took me to write this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I understand there is nothing complicated here, you have to save the alpha channels before performing the crop.

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng("./cover.png");
imagealphablending($img, false);
imagesavealpha($img, true);
$resource = imagecrop($img, ['x' => 0, 'y' => 0, 'width' => 500, 'height' => 500]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the GD library.
Then do the following:

```
   $img = imagecreatefrompng("./sample.png");
    imagealphablending($img, false);//set alphablending to false
    $img=imagecrop($img, array('x' => 0, 'y' =>0, 'width' => 200, 'height' => 200));
    imagesavealpha($img, true);//save alpha after croping
```

Comment: This answer does not add anything new from the other answer that was posted previously.

Comment: @tomerpacific executing imagesavealpha($img, true) after imagecrop() function saves the transparency.